# pandas pivot print values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a sql table that looks like this:

```
col1   col2 col3
1        a  0.5
1        b  0.2
2        a  0.3
2        b  0.4
```

i convert it into a pandas dataframe:

```
df_all = pd.DataFrame( [[ij for ij in i] for i in conversion_rows] )
df_pivot=df_all.pivot(index='col2', columns='col1', values='col3')
print df_pivot
```

of which i get this:

```
col1                  1         2 
dim_contact_channel                  
a                    0.5       0.3
b                    0.2       0.4
```

How do i get say print value of row 2 col 2 which is `0.4` for further manipulation?

Comment: ``df_pivot.loc['b', 2]`` or `df_pivot.iloc[1, 1]`? See the docs on indexing: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html